# hook_commerce_order_presave firing on page load

Tags: 7, commerce

I'm trying to run some code whenever an order is updated. I've found the function hook_commerce_order_presave which fulfils this purpose, but it seems this also fires on page load. Is this normal, or is there another module that would be causing this? Is there a more suitable function I could use?

Answer (score 0):

This is unusual. The *hook* should not be executed on every page load. You might want to check if some code in a custom module, custom theme, rule is causing an update of *commerce_order* which could trigger the hook.

To ensure that the order is updated on every page load, you can implement [`hook_entity_update()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_update/7.x), in your custom module

```
function MODULE_entity_update($entity, $type) {
  if ($type == 'commerce_order') {
    // Execute your code here.
  }
}
```

If the code inside `if` loop is still executed, you can be sure that the *something* is triggering update of commerce order on each page load. And you can proceed to find out what is the actual cause of the problem.

Comment: Yeah I've just tried hook_entity_update and the same thing occurs - the type is commerce_order. I thought it was unusual.

Comment: @Chris Hmm. Is it occurring on all pages? Or only on specific pages, like cart?

Comment: All pages, but strangely not every time. Every 2 or 3 refreshes. Running out of ideas here...

Comment: Ok I've narrowed it down to a call to commerce_cart_order_load in my template.php. Surely this shouldn't fire hook_entity_update???

Comment: @Chris : commerce_cart_order_load shouldn't trigger this either. Is anything changing in the order when the cart is loaded? That could trigger the hook.

Comment: I've further narrowed it down the commerce_discount module which invokes hook_commerce_cart_order_refresh() to apply discounts. Do you know any way around this?